# PLY parser accepts square and round brackets, but I only want it to accept round brackets

Tags: parsing, brackets, ply

I made a lexer and parser that does basic addition. In my lexer, the LPAREN and RPAREN tokens are ( and ) respectively, but for some reason, in the parser, it accepts the square [] brackets as well.

The token definitions in my lexer: 'r')' and r'('

regex in parser:
def p_term_expr(p):
'''expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN'''
p[0] = p[2]

Does anyone know how to change it so it only accepts round brackets?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. If you define lexer rules using the actual patterns `r')'` and `r'('`, lexer generation should fail with a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the brackets, as demonstrated in the [official docs](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply):

```
t_LPAREN  = r'\('
t_RPAREN  = r'\)'
```

Also, please post [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as noted by @sepp2k. This ensures that others (who're just seeing this issue) can understand the context better.

Comment: I would imagine that OP already has backslashes in their patterns. There are no backslashes in the question, sure, but as I said in my comment, the patterns shown in the question would cause a syntax error, not the issue that OP is describing. I doubt it's possible to know what causes OP's problem without seeing the real code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! It should fail with the lexical error immediately. OP probably has an issue in other token rules, as p[0] = p[2] basically ignores the matched parenthesis anyway, so it's easy to miss if they're ever being matched...